# How to prevent brace-initializer being interpreted as integer in function overload?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have an `Expression` class that stores algebraic terms. The public interface I want it to have is something like:

```
expr.add({1})      // add term "x1".         (error: code adds constant 1)
expr.add({0,1})    // add term "x0 * x1".
expr.add({0},2)    // add term "2 * x0"
expr.add(2)        // add constant 2
```

But I'm having the problem that `expr.add({1})` is being interpreted as adding the integer 1, not adding the vector containing 1. Is there any way I can fix the implementation below to allow for the interface above? (Or at the very least catch it?) Because typing out `expr.add(std::vector({1}))` is far too verbose.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

class Expression
{
    using var_t = unsigned int;
    using term_t = std::pair<int, std::vector<var_t>>;

    std::vector<term_t> terms;

  public:

    void add(const std::vector<var_t>& vars, int coeff=1)
    {
        std::cout << "Adding a term" << std::endl;
        terms.push_back(std::make_pair(coeff, vars));
    }
    void add(int constant)
    {
        std::cout << "Adding a constant" << std::endl;
        terms.push_back(std::make_pair(constant, std::vector<var_t>{}));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Expression expr;
    expr.add({1},1); // "Adding a term"
    expr.add({1});   // "Adding a constant"
    expr.add(1);     // "Adding a constant"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an overload for `initializer_list` which will bind to the argument if it's in a brace initializer

```
void add(std::initializer_list<var_t> vars, int coeff=1)
{
    add(std::vector<var_t>(vars), coeff);
}
```

In the implementation, you can just call the `vector` overload explicitly and/or give the user a warning.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/as9hcd6jd).

Answer (score 4):

You can change the parameter type to `std::initializer_list`, which would be preferred.

```
void add(std::initializer_list<var_t> vars, int coeff=1)
{
    std::cout << "Adding a term" << std::endl;
    terms.push_back(std::make_pair(coeff, std::vector<var_t>(vars)));
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1tZCLcLY6Owb21VB)

Comment: I would add the overload, instead of changing the existing one. Unless they want to disallow passing an existing vector.

Answer (score 2):

You may change it to `initializer_list` in the arguments.

```
void add(std::initializer_list<var_t> vars, int coeff=1)
```